# Why clone failed? couldn't find remote ref "refs/heads/origin/master"

Tags: git, kubernetes

I cloned locally podinfo(used for Flux practice)

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/v0.x
  remotes/origin/v1.x
  remotes/origin/v3.x
  remotes/origin/v5.x
```

Anyway

```
flux get sources git
```

shows

```
podinfo                     False       False   failed to checkout and determine revision: unable to clone 'https://github.com/dexterposh/podinfo': couldn't find remote ref "refs/heads/origin/master"
```

My podinfo.yaml

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
 name: podinfo
 namespace: flux-system
spec:
 interval: 30s
 ref:
  branch: origin/master
 url: https://github.com/dexterposh/podinfo
```

Why did checkout fail?

Comment: Note that the *clone* probably *succeeded*, except for the final checkout step. The reason is clear: there's no branch named `origin/master` in https://github.com/dexterposh/podinfo. Perhaps you wanted a different branch name, such as just plain `master`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `origin` to the branch ref. Just `branch: master` should do it:

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta1
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
 name: podinfo
 namespace: flux-system
spec:
 interval: 30s
 ref:
  branch: master
 url: https://github.com/dexterposh/podinfo
```